# Why is the condition that $f$ requires only simple poles in Mittag-Leffler's Expansion theorem necessary?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I was taking a look at the proof of the Mittag pole expansion [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_Expansion_Theorem). For the convenience of the reader, I will copy the statement here.

**Mittag-Leffler Expansion Theorem:**

Let $f$
be a meromorphic function that:

has only simple poles, is continuous, or has a removable singularity at $0$.

Let $X$ be the set of poles of $f$.

For $N\in\mathbb{N}$, let $C_N$ be a disk, centered at the origin, of radius $R_N$ where:

$R_N \to \infty$ as $N\to\infty$. $\partial C_N$ contains no poles of $f$ for any $N$. And there exists a real number $M>0$ independent of $N$ such that for all $z∈\partial C_N$
, $|f(z)|<M$, for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$.

Then:

$f(z)=f(0)+\sum_{n\in X} \mathrm{Res}(f,n)(\frac{1}{z−n}+\frac{1}{n})$

Where $\mathrm{Res}(f,n)$ denotes the residue of $f$ at $n$.

The proof makes complete sense to me. However, I do not understand why the condition that $f$ requires only simple poles is needed. If we remove the condition that '$f$ has only simple poles', the proof is still fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The right-hand side has only simply poles, therefore the formula *cannot* be valid if $f$ has multiple poles.

Comment: Thank you, though I still couldn't find what is wrong with the proof if the condition is removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expansion
$$
f(z)=f(0)+\sum_{n\in X} \operatorname{Res}(f,n)\left(\frac{1}{z−n}+\frac{1}{n} \right)
$$
cannot hold for meromorphic functions with multiple poles because the right-hand side has only simple poles.

The proof uses the formula
$$
\operatorname{Res}\left(g,n\right) = \lim_{z \to n} (z-n)g(z) \, ,
$$
applied to $g(z) = f(z)/(z-\zeta)$, and that is only valid at *simple* poles of $g$ (resp. $f$).